# Perl method and pass by reference

Tags: perl, oop, pass-by-reference

For me, Perl references are a hard thing to grasp. When reading to some OO-like scripts that use object methods, I never saw the object used as a reference. Even for big objects, that would benefit from being used as a reference instead of being copied to a subroutine (method).

[PerlMaven](https://perlmaven.com/methods-functions-and-subroutines-in-perl) says that:

> ```
> $p->a_method($value);
> ```
>
> Behind the scenes, perl will run
>
> ```
> a_method($p, $value);
> ```

But if `$p` is  huge object, wouldn't you want to pass it as a reference?

```
a_method(\$p, $value)
```

I have always understood that passing by reference can lead to a significant speed increase if the object is large. In OO, it is quite likely that you are working with large objects (e.g. a huge `XML::Twig`). So how would you call a method on such an object, when actually passing it as a reference to the subroutine?

Comment: Nit: `$p->a_method($value)` doesn't necessarily call a sub in the current package as that quote implies. `$p->a_method($value)` is closer to `my $sub = $p->can('a_method')->($p, $value);`

Comment: `$p` is a reference (a pointer on which you can't do arithmetic), and the reference is passed by reference (because all arguments are passed by reference in Perl). Both of those (independently) make the size of the object irrelevant for a method call, and the former makes the size of the object irrelevant for `my $self = shift;` too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$p` already contains a reference to the object. Method calls require a reference to the object, and it's this reference that's passed to the sub. So, $self is always a reference. See [perlobj](http://p3rl.org/perlobj) and [bless](http://p3rl.org/bless).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

{   package Class;

    sub new { bless {}, __PACKAGE__ }
    sub inf { ref shift }
}

my $o = 'Class'->new;
say $o->inf ? 'reference' : 'not a reference';
```

Output:

```
reference
```

Comment: Thanks, I could not find anything about this. The example from PerlMaven also confused me even more, because how it's re-written it seems that it's passed by value.

Comment: Well, it is - but only because the "reference" is a value. Bit like a pointer. (Not entirely though).

Comment: @Bram Vanroy, Re "*it seems that it's passed by value*", All arguments are passed by reference in Perl, though we usually proceed to make a copy of them (`my ($arg) = @_;`).

Comment: @choroba, Obviously a substantial edit. Feel free to revert.